# Better way to change content than over using .click and .html

Tags: jquery

So I'm working on a little side project to learn and play with jQuery and now looking to you all for reference. If you look at my sample you can get an idea of what I'm going for but I can tell I'm going about it all wrong.

The idea is to have the header contain the top level elements (drink names). By clicking on each drink  different sets of content will be displayed, within each of these different drink sections size can be changed as well to change the "code" boxes based off drink and size. Drink>Size>Code. Clicking a new drink will reset the size to "G" and the code boxes will be cleared to default. The buttons on the bottom should be different for each drink and will change the code boxes and be able to set a preferred size. The Americano section will give you the best idea of what I'm going for except I couldn't figure out how to select a prefered radio button. I just want to learn a better way to go about this problem, any references would be appreciated!

Here's a [demo](http://codepen.io/TonyJT/pen/QwEmRv) of what I've got.

html

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <ul class="navigation" role="navigation">
            <li id="nav-a"><a>Americano</a></li>
            <li id="nav-c"><a>Cappuccino</a></li>
            <!--<li id="nav-l"><a>Latte</a></li>
            <li id="nav-mac"><a>Macchiato</a></li>-->
            <li id="nav-m"><a>Mocha</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="main-wrap">
        <div id="sidebar">
            <div id="size">
                <p id="size-title">Cup size</p>
                <form>
                    <input type="radio" name="size" id="short" value="short" /> 
                    <label for="short">S</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="size" id="tall" value="tall" />     
                    <label for="tall">T</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="size" id="grande" value="grande" checked="checked"/>     
                    <label for="grande">G</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="size" id="venti" value="venti" />     
                    <label for="venti">V</label>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="cup-container">
                <img src="http://tonyjt.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Empty.png" class="cup">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="content-wrap">
            <div id="mid-wrap">
                <div id="key">Key                       
                </div>
                <div id="info"> about the drink</div>
                <div id="examples">
                    <section class="ex-btns">
                        <button class="btn" id="default-btn">Default</button>
                        <button class="btn" id="ex1-btn">Example 1</button>
                        <button class="btn" id="ex2-btn">Example 2</button>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="code">Code
                <p class="box-font">Decaf</p>
                <div class="boxes" id="decaf"><p></p></div>
                <p class="box-font">Shots</p>
                <div class="boxes" id="shots"><p></p></div>
                <p class="box-font">Syrup</p>   
                <div class="boxes" id="syrup"><p></p></div>
                <p class="box-font">Milk</p>
                <div class="boxes" id="milk"><p></p></div>
                <p class="box-font">Custom</p>
                <div class="boxes" id="custom"><p></p></div>
                <p class="box-font">Drink</p>
                <div class="boxes" id="drink"><p></p></div> 
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"><strong>Barista Tip:</strong>
        <p id="tip"></p>
    </div>
</div>  
</body>
```

css

```
body {
background:#eee
}

#header,#footer {
background:#006341
}

#main-wrap {
overflow:hidden;
background:#d9d9d9
}

#content-wrap {
background:#c5c5c5
}

.code {
width:80px;
height:500px;
float:right;
background:#fff
}

#key,#examples {
height:80px;
background:#000
}

#main-wrap>div {
height:500px
}

#header {
height:40px;
line-height:40px;
text-align:center;
font-size:30px
}

#footer {
height:50px
}

#container {
width:980px;
position:absolute;
margin:0 auto
}

#sidebar {
float:left;
width:300px;
background:#f0f0f0
}

#mid-wrap {
float:left;
width:600px;
height:500px;
overflow:hidden
}

#key {
width:600px;
color:#fff
}

#info {
height:340px
}

.info {
float:left
}

.boxes {
width:50px;
height:40px;
border:2px solid #000;
margin-top:4px;
margin-left:14px
}

.boxes p {
text-align:center;
margin:0;
padding-top:1px;
font:32px/40px "Shadows Into Light Two"
}

#custom {
width:60px;
margin-left:9px
}

#size {
height:115px;
top:0
}

.cup {
width:250px;
padding-top:4px
}

#cup-container {
margin:0;
padding-left:25px;
bottom:0
}

form {
position:relative;
background:#fff;
padding:10px;
display:inline-block;
margin:5px 31px;
}

input {
display:none
}

input:checked+label {
background:#000;
color:#fff
}

label {
font-family:lato;
cursor:pointer;
display:inline-block;
margin-right:2px;
width:50px;
height:40px;
text-align:center;
line-height:40px
}

label:last-child {
margin-right:0
}

label:hover {
background:#7f7f7f
}

#header,#footer,#tip {
font-family:lato;
color:#fff;
font-weight:300
}

#footer,#tip {
line-height:50px;
padding-left:15px
}

.code,#key,#size-title {
text-align:center;
font-family:lato
}

#size-title {
margin:0;
padding:5px 0
}

.box-font {
margin-bottom:5px;
margin-top:10px;
font:300 16px lato
}

#tip {
display:inline-block;
margin:0;
padding-left:5px
}

#header li {
text-align:left;
display:inline;
margin:0;
padding:2px 10px;
line-height:40px;
cursor:help
}

#header ul {
padding:0;
margin:0
}

#header ul li:hover {
background:#eee;
color:#000
}

#size li {
text-align:left;
display:inline
}
```

jQuery

```
function myFunction() {

/*************************************   A    ****************************/ 

 $('#nav-a').click(function() {
  $('#decaf p').html('');
  $('#shots p').html('3');
  $('#syrup p').html('');
  $('#milk p').html('');
  $('#custom p').html('');
  $('#drink p').html('A');

  $('#grande').attr('checked',true);

  $('#info').html('Americano blaw blaw blaw');

  $(".cup").attr('src',"http://tonyjt.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Drink-A.png");

  $('#tip').html('Put a sleeve on the cup before you add the hot water.');

                                    /*  Size    ****************************/

     $('#short').click(function() {
           $('#shots p').html('1');
           })
     $('#tall').click(function() {
           $('#shots p').html('2');
           }) 
     $('#grande').click(function() {
           $('#shots p').html('3');
           })
     $('#venti').click(function() {
           $('#shots p').html('4');
           })   



     $('#default-btn').click(function() {
          $('#decaf p').html('');
          $('#shots p').html('');
          $('#syrup p').html('');
          $('#milk p').html('');
          $('#custom p').html('');
          $('#drink p').html('A');
          $('#info').html('Standard comes with...');
      }) 
     $('#ex1-btn').click(function() {
          $('#decaf p').html('X');
          $('#shots p').html('');
          $('#syrup p').html('2CD');
          $('#milk p').html('');
          $('#custom p').html('W/R');
          $('#drink p').html('A');
          $('#info').html('In this exapmle...1');
          $('#venti').attr('checked',true);
           }) 
     $('#ex2-btn').click(function() {
          $('#decaf p').html('');
          $('#shots p').html('');
          $('#syrup p').html('CL');
          $('#milk p').html('S');
          $('#custom p').html('');
          $('#drink p').html('A');
          $('#info').html('In this exapmle...2');
          $('#tall').attr('checked',true);  
          })                      
});


/*************************************   C    ****************************/ 

$('#nav-c').click(function() {
  $('#decaf p').html('');
  $('#shots p').html('2');
  $('#syrup p').html('');
  $('#milk p').html('2%');
  $('#custom p').html('');
  $('#drink p').html('C');
  $('#grande').attr('checked',true);

  $(".cup").attr('src',"http://tonyjt.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Drink-C.png");

  $('#tip').html('Fill the milk pitcher to the line under the size you are making. Ex: Fill to the Tall line if you are making a Grande.');



     $('#short').click(function() {
           $('#shots p').html('1');
           })
     $('#tall').click(function() {
           $('#shots p').html('1');
           }) 
     $('#grande').click(function() {
           $('#shots p').html('2');
           })
     $('#venti').click(function() {
           $('#shots p').html('2');
           })   

});

/*************************************   M    ****************************/ 

$('#nav-m').click(function() {
  $('#decaf p').html('');
  $('#shots p').html('2');
  $('#syrup p').html('4M');
  $('#milk p').html('2%');
  $('#custom p').html('WC');
  $('#drink p').html('M');

  $(".cup").attr('src',"http://tonyjt.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Drink-M.png");

  $('#tip').html('Swirl the cup while the shots are pulling into it. This melts down the mocha to prevent it sitting at the bottom.');


     $('#short').click(function() {
           $('#shots p').html('1');
           $('#syrup p').html('2M')
           })
     $('#tall').click(function() {
           $('#shots p').html('1');
           $('#syrup p').html('3M')
           }) 
     $('#grande').click(function() {
           $('#shots p').html('2');
           $('#syrup p').html('4M')
           })
     $('#venti').click(function() {
           $('#shots p').html('2');
           $('#syrup p').html('5M')

           }) 

});
}
$(document).ready(myFunction);
```

Comment: The usual way to set a radio button default is with `$("#id").prop("checked", true)`. As for a better way for changing content: generally you can put all your content in hidden HTML and then only use the javascript controls to toggle the CSS `display` between `none` and the initial value (then the radio default becomes a non-issue, too)

Comment: ahh .prop I was putting .attr, now working thanks! I will have to mess around with toggle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of jQuery usage, i do not believe that you are going about it in the wrong way at all. an ideal way to do this may be through PHP, where the elements are all simply pulled from a database. But through jquery `.click()` or other ways of handling onclick events will be used substantially. another method could be through the use of CSS classes with  `.addClass()` ,`.removeClass()` and `.toggleClass()`. if you need to simply not display a button or to display different styles.

But i think that you are not going about this in a bad way.